# R error for Psych: Error in apply(x[1:(n.obs - lag), ], 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm) : dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r

I have a dataframe. Call it "data" for simplicity.

```
structure(list(study_id = structure(c(001, 001, 002, 002, 
                                      003, 003), format.spss = "F6.0", display_width = 0L), Date = structure(c(18584, 
                                                                                                               18584, 18585, 18585, 18585, 18585), format.spss = "DATE11", display_width = 0L, class = "Date"), 
               SignalNumber = structure(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L), 
               Negative = structure(c(1, 3.3, 1.5, 4, NA, 1.5), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L), 
               Positive = structure(c(4.33333333333333, NA, 2.66666666666667, NA, 3, 4), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                   -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see, there are repeated study_id's with observations at different sessions. Some observations have NA in either only `Positive` or `Negative` and some have NA in both.

I'm trying to use the `psych` package to run an autocorrelation on my full data:

```
mssd(data$Negative,group=data$study_id, lag = 1,na.rm=TRUE)
rmssd(data$Negative,group=data$study_id, lag=1, na.rm=TRUE)
autoR(data$Negative,group=data$study_id,lag=1,na.rm=TRUE, use="pairewise")
```

`mssd()` and `rmssd()` work on my full data as expected. Running `autoR()` gets me the following error: Error in apply(x[1:(n.obs - lag), ], 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm) :
dim(X) must have a positive length

Not sure what's going on here. My full dataset has many more data observations (into the thousands). This example I posted is working the same way as my code, however.

Is it because of the standing NA's? If that's the case, shouldn't the `na.rm` argument remove them? Besides, when I used `na.omit()` on my data I still got this error. Can't seem to find an answer specific to the `autoR` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are relatively sparse, but based on the source code one issue could be the number of variables being passed to the function. If you subset your dataframe to columns "study_id, Negative, Positive" and change "group" to NULL, the function runs as expected:

```r
library(psych)

data <- structure(list(study_id = structure(c(001, 001, 002, 002, 
                                              003, 003), format.spss = "F6.0", display_width = 0L), Date = structure(c(18584, 
                                                                                                                       18584, 18585, 18585, 18585, 18585), format.spss = "DATE11", display_width = 0L, class = "Date"), 
                       SignalNumber = structure(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L), 
                       Negative = structure(c(1, 3.3, 1.5, 4, NA, 1.5), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L), 
                       Positive = structure(c(4.33333333333333, NA, 2.66666666666667, NA, 3, 4), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                           -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

mssd(data$Negative,group=data$study_id, lag = 1,na.rm=TRUE)
#>   [,1]
#> 1 5.29
#> 2 6.25
#> 3  NaN
rmssd(data$Negative,group=data$study_id, lag=1, na.rm=TRUE)
#>   [,1]
#> 1  2.3
#> 2  2.5
#> 3  NaN
autoR(data$Negative,group=data$study_id,lag=1,na.rm=TRUE, use="pairwise")
#> Error in apply(x[1:(n.obs - lag), ], 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm): dim(X) must have a positive length

autoR(data[,c(1,4,5)],group=NULL,lag=1,na.rm=TRUE, use = "pairwise")
#> 
#> Autocorrelations 
#> study_id Negative Positive 
#>     0.79    -0.89       NA

result <- autoR(data[,c(1,4,5)],group=NULL,lag=1,na.rm=TRUE, use = "pairwise")
str(result)
#> List of 2
#>  $ autoR: Named num [1:3] 0.786 -0.886 NA
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "study_id" "Negative" "Positive"
#>  $ rssd : Named num [1:3] 0.632 1.922 0.577
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "study_id" "Negative" "Positive"
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "psych" "autoR"
result$autoR
#>   study_id   Negative   Positive 
#>  0.7857143 -0.8856090         NA
result$rssd
#>  study_id  Negative  Positive 
#> 0.6324555 1.9222383 0.5773503
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

When you try this on your actual data, try "group=data$study_id" and see if the function throws an error; it could help with troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: This was very helpful! I'm getting something that makes a bit more sense now, even when specifying group as the study_id. It must be something to do with all of the columns. I can even only specific columns 4 and 5 in my data and still get the same answer when I run. Now to see if these values are actually of use to us...but thank you for your help with this weird error!

Comment: You're very welcome; thanks for including all the relevant info in your question :)